Неизвестная Ошибка в Unity
При попытке обновить Package Manager UI в Unity выбивает это окно подскажите пожалуйста кто знает что делать целый день сижу уже в поиске решение данной проблемы заранее благодарю

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.
